# Trying to get a match with regex but failing

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the following:

```
Which of the following formulas are correct?
```

With:

```
Regex = @"Which (of the following )?(((is)|(is a)|(are)) correct)(?<result>.*?)[?:]"
```

But it's not matching. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Which options did you pass along with the regex? Are you ignoring whitespace?

Comment: Is there something I can put in there that will match any word or string of words like "formulas" ?

Comment: If you don't care about the text between "Which" and "correct", you can use @"Which.*?correct(?<result>.*?)[?:]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a sub-pattern that matches the `formulas` part of your input string:

```
Which (of the following )?(formulas )?(((is)|(is a)|(are)) correct)(?<result>.*?)[?:]
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Update:** If you want to match *any* word and not just `formulas`, replace the indicated sub-pattern:

```
(\w+ )?
```

Which roughly means, "one or more word characters, followed by a space; or nothing at all."

Please take a look at the MSDN page [**Regular Expression Language Elements**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). It explains the basic building blocks that make up .NET regular expression patterns.

Comment: But what if I want to match any string of things there?

Comment: @Marianne, now you're asking a different question, which means that (next time) you should either edit your original question above to make it reflect your *actual* question, or ask a new one. For this time, I've updated my answer.